# Поведение пустого цикла for с точки зрения стандарта

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, стандарт, задание-на-собеседовании

Какое поведение ожидать от кода с точки зрения стандарта?

```
int main(){for(;;){}}
```

1. Ошибка компиляции (CE)
2. Ошибка времени выполнения (RE)
3. Неопределённое поведение (UB)
4. Неспецифицированное поведение (unspecified)
5. Зависит от реализации (implementation defined)
6. Корректная программа (well-formed)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131141/discussion-on-question-by-karmik----for----).

Comment: Нормальный же вопрос, как минимум потому что половина комментаторов не знаю ответ. Может людей смутили варианты ответа, и они приняли это за домашку?..

Comment: @HolyBlackCat эта штука со всех сторон выглядит как душное задание с собеседования / экзамена, возможно со встроенной подставой - напрашивается ответ 6, ты отвечаешь, потом тебе предьявляют, что на самом деле ответ 3 и сажают в лужу. Какую же информацию о кандидате дает ответ на это задание - трудно сказать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, так давайте переоткроем его. Я тоже не знаю, как там с т.з. стандарта, но с позиций здравого смысла это д.б. бескончный цикл `L: jmp L` (если конкретная система команд позволяет, то ровно одна команда). Кто и как и для чего может это использовать, очевидно не должно слишком волновать авторов стандарта. (Кстати, де-факто стандарт (g++) делает именно такой код)

Comment: @avp - нормальная практика на AVR - навешать векторов прерываний, а главную программу загнать в бесконечный цикл.

Comment: @gbg, а вы то, зачем этот вопрос ззкрыли?

Comment: @avp я объяснил выше -  вопрос выглядит как целиком скопированное задание с экзамена/интервью. Как будто некто прямо сейчас сдает экзамен и желает накраудфайндить себе высший балл

Comment: @gbg, разве это важно? Вопрос-то, на самом деле, довольно интересный. Дискуссионный, я бы сказал (неужели забыл, SO (как и Дума) ...?)

Comment: _напрашивается ответ 6, ты отвечаешь, потом тебе предьявляют, что на самом деле ответ 3_ Оба пункта подходят. Правильный ответ должен быть полным. Ещё в ответ можно включить "возможно, 1 и 2".

Answer (score 9):

Реализация может быть уверена, что **любой поток** в конечном итоге выполнит одно из следующих действий:

1. прервётся,
2. вызовет библиотечную функцию ввода-вывода,
3. выполнит доступ к некоторому volatile glvalue,
4. выполнит операцию синхронизации, либо атомарную операцию.

[intro.progress / 1](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.progress#1):

> The implementation may assume that **any thread** will eventually do one of the following:
>
> 1. terminate,
> 2. make a call to a library I/O function,
> 3. perform an access through a volatile glvalue, or
> 4. perform a synchronization operation or an atomic operation.
>
> [*Note 1*: This is intended to allow compiler transformations such as removal of empty loops, even when termination cannot be proven.
> — *end note*]

Приведённая программа не делает ничего из написанного выше, т.е. нарушает требования стандарта языка, следовательно, её поведение не определено.

---

> Это раздел "Multi-threaded executions and data races", но где здесь многопоточность?

В приведённой цитате ничего не говорится о количестве потоков. **Любой поток** должен удовлетворять приведённым ограничениям, включая главный поток программы, в рамках которого выполняется функция `main`. [basic.start.main / 1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#1):

> [...] Executing a program starts a main thread of execution in which the `main` function is invoked. [...]

---

> в C++20/23 не написано прямо и недвусмысленно, что это UB

Для того, чтобы поведение некоторого кода было неопределённым не требуется явным образом использовать слова «undefined behavior». Поведение программы не определено также в том случае, если стандарт языка явным образом не специфицирует наблюдаемое поведение. [defns.undefined / Note 1](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.undefined#note-1):

> Undefined behavior may be expected when this document omits any explicit definition of behavior or when a program uses an erroneous construct or erroneous data.

Также см. стандарт языка C, [n1570, 4 / 2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtimeconstraint
> is violated, the behavior is undefined. Undefined behavior is otherwise
> indicated in this International Standard by the words ‘‘undefined behavior’’ or **by the
> omission of any explicit definition of behavior**. There is no difference in emphasis among
> these three; they all describe ‘‘behavior that is undefined’’.

Приведённая в начале ответа цитата не описывает явным образом, что произойдёт при нарушении указанных ограничений, следовательно их нарушение вызывает неопределённое поведение.

---

ОК, подойдём к вопросу с другой стороны...

Посмотрим документ [N1528: Why undefined behavior for infinite loops?](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1528.htm) от 2010 года в котором один из участников групп WG14 и WG21 по стандартизации языков C и C++ обсуждает формулировку пункта 6.8.5p6 черновика стандарта языка C. На тот момент она выглядела так ( [N1509: Optimizing away infinite loops](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1509.pdf)):

> 6 An iteration statement that performs no input/output operations,
> does not access volatile objects, and performs no
> synchronization or atomic operations in its body, controlling
> expression, or (in the case of a for statement) its expression-3,
> may be assumed by the implementation to terminate.<sup>154)</sup>
>
> 154. This is intended to allow compiler transformations such as
>      removal of empty loops even when termination cannot be
>      proven.

В приведённой формулировке также не используются слова «undefined behavior», однако, смысл написанного [поясняется](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1528.htm) вполне прямо и не двусмысленно:

> As N1509 correctly points out, the current draft essentially gives undefined behavior to infinite loops in 6.8.5p6.

---

> но с позиций здравого смысла это д.б. бескончный цикл

В такой простой программе

```
int main(){for(;;){}}
```

мне не удалось добиться иного поведения кроме как бесконечный цикл. Поэтому рассмотрим более сложный пример, придуманный John Regehr в статье [C Compilers Disprove Fermat’s Last Theorem](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/140). (Я немного подправил код из статьи, но суть не изменилась):

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

bool fermat ()
{
    const long long MAX = 1'000'000;
    long long a=1, b=1, c=1;
    
    for (;;) {
        if (a*a*a == b*b*b+c*c*c)
            return true;
        
        a++;
        if (a>MAX) {
            a=1;
            b++;
        }
        
        if (b>MAX) {
            b=1;
            c++;
        }
        
        if (c>MAX) {
            c=1;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

int main() {
    if (fermat()) {
        cout << "Fermat's Last Theorem has been disproved.\n";
    } else {
        cout << "Fermat's Last Theorem has not been disproved.\n";
    }
}
```

Данная программа пытается найти контрпример к [Великой теореме Ферма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0) полным перебором. Она перебирает все возможные тройки чисел `{a, b, c}`, где `a`, `b` и `c` принимают целочисленные значения из отрезка `[1; 1'000'000]`.

Функция `fermat` содержит бесконечный цикл (`for (;;)`) из которого можно выйти только в том случае, если программа сможет найти пример, опровергающий Великую теорему Ферма, что невозможно.

Так как функция `fermat` никогда не прервёт выполнение и не осуществляет никакого другого наблюдаемого поведения, то поведение приведённой программы не определено.

Результат выполнения примера *может быть* следующим ([clang](https://ideone.com/xosQ8F), [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff57cdcd42b367cf)):

> Fermat's Last Theorem has been disproved.

Компилятор смог понять, что цикл на самом деле бесконечный и просто выбросил его (причём в однопоточной программе). Более того фактически программа ведёт себя так, словно смогла опровергнуть Великую теорему Ферма, что довольно контринтуитивно.

---

Связанные вопросы на enSO:

- [Is this infinite recursion UB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5905155)
- [Optimizing away a "while(1);" in C++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3592557)

Comment: Это раздел "Multi-threaded executions and data races", но где здесь многопоточность?

Comment: @Mikhailo Название раздела не значит, что это действует только на многопоточные программы. Вот [пример](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sa6eWGf4o) однопоточной программы, которая падает на бесконечном цикле.

Comment: Это, как я понимаю, не падает, а убивается на сайте по времени выполнения - как тут: https://ideone.com/flABN7 Вы привели конкретный компилятор, а где гарантии его правильности? VC++ например компилирует и уходит в бесконечный цикл. Почему вы считаете, что он неправ?

Comment: @Mikhailo, и что, что в разделе многопоточность? Сказано, что «The implementation may assume that **any thread** will eventually do one of the following». По вашему, главный поток, не является потоком выполнения (_thread of execution_)?

Comment: @Mikhailo Падает, я локально проверил. Все компиляторы правы, UB все-таки. :)

Comment: @Mikhailo Вот [еще](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1528.htm) интересное чтиво. О пользе запрета бесконечных циклов, в т.ч. для однопоточных программ.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, с чего вы взяли, что clang **это правильный компайлер?*** (g++ вставляет в это-же код бесконечный цикл после первого `puts()` (и с -O2 не делает  второй `puts()` ))

Comment: @avp Я понимаю что поведение кланга - не железный аргумент. :) Тогда вот еще аргумент: на этапе компиляции невозможно определить, будет ли поднят поток из другой единицы трансляции или нет. Поэтому в правиле, которое действует только на однопоточную программу, нет смысла, ведь компилятор вынужден считать любую программу многопоточной.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, если компилятор (реализующий стандарты языка) считает себя таким умным, то это веский довод сменить язык.

Comment: @avp, добавил в ответ пример, когда g++ удаляет бесконечный цикл.

Comment: @wololo, да, вижу (у меня 7.5.0 он пока знает только -std=c++1z (-std=c++2a не знает) и он еще работает (циклиться)). Осталось присоединиться к Линусу и повторить, что все новые версии безнадежно испорчены и не стоит ими пользоваться.

Comment: Отсюда следует, что все программы для микроконтроллеров, в которых вся работа выполняется в прерываниях, а основной *поток* зациклен, по факту, эксплуатируют UB?

Comment: @gbg Ага. Чтобы все было легально, можно, например, volatile счетчик инкрементировать в цикле...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - это сожрет целый регистр, плохая идея

Comment: Следовательно, придется делать вставку на ассемблере.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос неточно сформулирован.

Если

```
int main(){for(;;){}}
```

Это вся программа, то к ней нет претензий.

Однако, если это многопоточная программа, т.е. в программе есть ещё статические конструкторы порождающие потоки, то нарушаются требования C++20 п. 6.9.2.2 Forward progress. Таким образом получаем: неопределенное поведение (undefined behavior).

Яндекс в помощь: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Forward_progress

P.S.

Как заметил @HolyBlackCat (уже в чате), clang 13.0.0 с ключом `-O` порождает в этом случае безусловно ошибочный код.

Причём ошибочный код порождается даже для программ, которые гарантированно завершаются (т.е. не нарушающих требования п. 6.9.2.2), скажем:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    system("(sleep 1; kill $PPID)&");
    for(;;)
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

или

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    alarm(1);
    for(;;)
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

Возможно это ошибка компилятора clang-13, возможно это ошибка в стандарте C++20, но clang-13 не соответствует С++20 и текущим черновикам C++2x.

Т.е. возможно в стандарте C++2х следует исправить:

- В п. 6.9.2.3 строка 1.1 следует написать не просто "terminate", а без учёта сигналов, и точно указать, что это UB;
- В приложении C указать, что теряется совместимость однопоточных приложений использующих сигналы.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131171/discussion-on-answer-by-serge3leo----for----).

Comment: Аргумент про `alarm` и `system` интересный, но `alarm` нестандартный, а про `system` в стандарте есть забавная приписка, что он [*"might ... cause the
program ... to behave in a non-conforming manner"*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , где это в стандарте C++20 написано, что корректное использование POSIX - это UB? Не суть, в C++20 более менее подробно описано функционирование сигналов, и завершение приложения/потока в результате обработчика SIGINT/SIGTERM/... и др., предоставленного программой, или по-умолчанию, это ни разу не UB. И вполне соответствует требованию завершения потока, рано или поздно, C++20 п. 6.9.2.2. А clang 13 - не соответствует.

Comment: `ошибочный код порождается даже для программ, которые гарантированно завершаются`. Не согласен. Использование `alarm` и `system` завершает поток способом, который реализация не может контролировать. Пусть есть код `long long sum=0; for (long long i=0; i<10'000'000'000; ++i) sum+=1;` Может ли компилятор заменять цикл конкретным значением, посчитанным на этапе компиляции? А если прежде была вызвана гипотетическая функция `foo()`, которая говорит ОС: пиши в случайные моменты времени в стековые переменные потока случайные значения? Должен ли компилятор учитывать такой вариант при оптимизации?