# Первый раз вижу эту ошибку

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Я эксперементировал с кодом c++ и получил странную ошибку segmentation fault
Вот код

```
#include <iostream>
void void1()
{
    void1();
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void1();
}
```

Comment: Потребление памяти вылезло за пределы стека, наверное

Comment: Каждый вызов функции `void1` приводит к тому, что потребляется небольшой кусочек стека. Так как функция `void1` вызывает саму себя неограниченно, а стек имеет конечный размер, то в какой-то момент происходит обращение к памяти за пределами стека, что и приводит к [ошибке сегментации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Comment: Хотя компилятор может заметить, что здесь [хвостовая рекурсия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F), и заменить бесконечную рекурсию на бесконечный цикл. Тогда ошибки сегментации не будет, а программа [просто «зависнет»](https://godbolt.org/z/jEe57co9d).

Comment: А вообще, с точки зрения стандарта языка поток выполнения, зайдя в функцию `void1`, останется в ней навсегда, не производя никаких наблюдаемых эффектов. Такая ситуация вызывает неопределённое поведение — никаких ограничений на поведение программы не налагается. Поэтому компилятор может, например, [устранить вызов функции `void1`](https://godbolt.org/z/55zc8racc).

Comment: @wololo, почему UB? Вроде просто оптимизация?

Comment: @Qwertiy, смотрите раздел _progress guarantee_ на [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model). Ну, и здесь этот вопрос [также обсуждался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1345708).

Comment: Я хочу устранить ошибку сегментации, хочу узнать как мой телефон себя поведет

Comment: А что этот код должен делать по вашей задумке?

Comment: Не знаю, может телефон зависнет.

Comment: Я вообще хотел написать программу для того что бы мой телефон залагал

Answer (score 2):

`main` вызывает `void1`, которая вызывает `void1`, которая вызывает `void1`, которая вызывает `void1`, которая вызывает `void1` ...

Переполнение стека - очевидно же.